# Added a new module named TMP under the dlls directory in the Wine

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, debian, wine

Based on wine9.0 and debian11 / OpenGL renderer string: `NVDIA GeForce GT 730/PCIe/SSE2`.

I have added a new module named `TMP` under the dlls directory in the Wine source code. The compilation and installation processes seem to be successful, and the tmp.dll and tmp.so files are generated. Then, I created two files user32.c and win32u.c in the dlls/tmp/ directory.

Contents of user32.c file:

```c
    BOOLEAN WINAPI founction_A(){
     return TRUE;
    }
```

Contents of win32u.c file:

```c
    #if 0
    #pragma makedep unix
    #endif
    __attribute__((visibility ("default"))) BOOL WINAPI founction_B(){
     return TRUE;
    }
```

Contents of main.c file:

```c
void *__wine_syscall_dispatcher = NULL;
static unixlib_handle_t nfs_handle;
#ifdef _WIN64
#define SYSCALL_ENTRY(id,name,args) __ASM_SYSCALL_FUNC( id + 0x2000, name )
ALL_SYSCALLS64
#else
#define SYSCALL_ENTRY(id,name,args) __ASM_SYSCALL_FUNC( id + 0x2000, name, args )
DEFINE_SYSCALL_HELPER32()
ALL_SYSCALLS32
#endif
#undef SYSCALL_ENTRY

BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE inst, DWORD reason, void *reserved )
{
    HMODULE ntdll;
    void **dispatcher_ptr;
    const UNICODE_STRING ntdll_name = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING( L"ntdll.dll" );
    switch (reason)
    {
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        TRACE("NFS DllMain DLL_THREAD_ATTACH %d \n", __LINE__, reason);
        LdrDisableThreadCalloutsForDll( inst );
        if (__wine_syscall_dispatcher) break;  /* already set through Wow64Transition */
        LdrGetDllHandle( NULL, 0, &ntdll_name, &ntdll );
        dispatcher_ptr = RtlFindExportedRoutineByName( ntdll, "__wine_syscall_dispatcher" );
        __wine_syscall_dispatcher = *dispatcher_ptr ;
        if (!NtQueryVirtualMemory( GetCurrentProcess(), inst, MemoryWineUnixFuncs,
                                   &nfs_handle, sizeof(nfs_handle), NULL ))
            __wine_unix_call( nfs_handle, 0, NULL );
        break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            TRACE( "[%d]======>reason:%d \n", __LINE__, reason);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Contents of tmp.spec file:

```
@ stdcall founction_A()
@ stdcall -syscall  founction_B()
```

Contents of dlls/tmp/Makefile.in file:

```
    MODULE   =  tmp.dll
    UNIXLIB  = tmp.so
    IMPORTLIB = tmp
    SOURCES = \
     main.c \
     user32.c \
     win32u.c \
```

I added a reference to `tmp` in dlls/user32/Makefile.in:

```
IMPORTS   = $(PNG_PE_LIBS) gdi32 sechost advapi32 kernelbase win32u tmp
```

Then, in dlls/user32/win.c, I called `founction_A`.

I also added a reference to `tmp` in dlls/win32u/Makefile.in:

```
IMPORTS   = ntdll winecrt0 tmp
UNIX_LIBS    =  -ltmp $(CARBON_LIBS) $(APPKIT_LIBS) $(PTHREAD_LIBS) -lm
```

Then, in dlls/win32u/windows.c, I called `founction_B`.

After executing `configure.ac` and running `tools/make_specfile`, I generated `ALL_SYSCALLS32` successfully. However,  When launching an application with the compiled Wine, Wine automatically copies the `tmp.DLL` file to the drive `C/windows/system32` and drive In `c/windows/syswow64`. Everything looks great.

But various strange issues occur. For example, when starting Foxmail, I receive the following error message:

```
0034:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
0034:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
0034:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0074:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
0074:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
0074:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
002c:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
002c:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
002c:fixme:font:opentype_enum_font_names handle name format 1
0024:err:module:loader_init "comctl32.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
0024:err:module:loader_init Initializing dlls for L"C:\\Foxmail 7.2\\Foxmail.exe" failed, status c0000005
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: base on wine9.0 and debian11